# Using multithreading Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsoup

I am fetching thousands of URLs and parsing tables from it using `parseDocument(doc)`. It would take hours to parse all tables, so I wanted to use threads to parse a lot of them at the same time, but don't know to do it.

The code below is a for loop that I need to use threads on:

```
for(int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlList.get(i)).get();
    reader.add(parseDocument(doc));
}
```

Comment: Yeah there isn't very much documentation/examples out there on threading...

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone I believe the comment was made by RobOhRob sarcastically.

Comment: Please see to ComparableFeature + ExcutorService for thread pool, it is easiest way use multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
         Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
               public void run() { 
                  try {
                     //parsedocument( urlList.get(i))           
                   } catch (Exception e) {   //Catching exeptions
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
              }
          });
          t.start();

     }
```

We create a thread variable called 't' that we could use. For example, can wait for it to finish using .Join(). A thread requires a run void where the actual operations will execute, this is because it uses something called "runnable" which is an interface that needs that Run method. Here you would parse the document. Finally, we start the thread by call t.start().

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone explaining the threads helps me personaly understand threads better